# Hard?: Spring security on classes that are not Spring Beans?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Definitely need some expert help with this!  I think this is mainly a Spring Security question, but as I don't know for sure, so I am also tagging with the general Spring tag!

When the Application Context is loaded (mine is all via Java Config, though I don't believe that matters), the "DefaultListableBeanFactory" is processed and eventually (via the ProxyFactory) Spring Security Advisors are added.  This is great when I have Spring Beans as I have Permissions that need authorization.

My question is: how do I get the same effect when I no longer require those classes to be Spring Beans?  Said differently, if I have an object instance created as a singleton bean via Java Config and the authorization is working correctly, is it possible to maintain that with the object instance being a POJO?  Again, for the experts, I want the interception chain returned in the JdkDynamicAopProxy to contain the Spring Security interceptors.

And "no", I am not really expecting an answer to this, maybe just hoping!!!

Comment: Why do you need the pojo to *not* be a spring bean?

Comment: That is a side issue really, if it can't be done, then perhaps, I'll have to confront alternatives.

Comment: SpringSecurity can protect HTTP URLs. Will it help you?

Comment: No, unfortunately that won't help.  Multiple ways to have this code executed and need the auth checks there all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add security interceptors to beans not instantiated by spring container
switch `global-security` tag to mode `aspectj` and weave the provided `AnnotationSecurityAspect` in the aspecj module.

For your second question I suppose that you want to do one of the following:

- Use a `ProxyFactoryBean` to secure a bean.
- Create security proxies programmatically:  Use `ProxyFactory.addAdvice()` method.
- Add the security interceptor to all proxies created by an `AutoProxyCreator`: This usually don't needed, but you can use the `AbstractAutoProxyCreator.interceptorNames` property to add common interceptors.  The `global-security` tag parser uses a generated name for the `MethodSecurityInterceptor`, so you need to configure the interceptor manually and set a consistent `SecurityMetadataSource`.